# Parallel processing in Dot Product

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran, intel

I am having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to get a simple Dot Product calculation to parallel process on a Fortran code compiled by the Intel ifort compiler v 16. I have the section of code below, it is part of a program used for a more complex process, but this is where most of the time is spent by the program:

```
double precision function ddot(n,dx,incx,dy,incy)
c
c     forms the dot product of two vectors.
c     uses unrolled loops for increments equal to one.
c     jack dongarra, linpack, 3/11/78.
c     modified 12/3/93, array(1) declarations changed to array(*)
c
      double precision dx(*),dy(*),dtemp
      integer i,incx,incy,ix,iy,m,mp1,n
c
      CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(12)
      ddot = 0.0d0
      dtemp = 0.0d0
      if(n.le.0)return
      if(incx.eq.1.and.incy.eq.1)go to 20
c
c        code for unequal increments or equal increments
c          not equal to 1
c
      ix = 1
      iy = 1
      if(incx.lt.0)ix = (-n+1)*incx + 1
      if(incy.lt.0)iy = (-n+1)*incy + 1
      do 10 i = 1,n
        dtemp = dtemp + dx(ix)*dy(iy)
        ix = ix + incx
        iy = iy + incy
   10 continue
      ddot = dtemp
      return
c
c        code for both increments equal to 1
c
c
c        clean-up loop
c
   20 m = mod(n,5)
      if( m .eq. 0 ) go to 40
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
!$OMP& DEFAULT(NONE) SHARED(dx,dy,m) PRIVATE(i)
!$OMP& SCHEDULE(STATIC)
!$OMP& REDUCTION( + : dtemp )
      do 30 i = 1,m
        dtemp = dtemp + dx(i)*dy(i)
   30 continue
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
      if( n .lt. 5 ) go to 60
   40 mp1 = m + 1
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
!$OMP& DEFAULT(NONE) SHARED(dx,dy,n,mp1) PRIVATE(i)
!$OMP& SCHEDULE(STATIC)
!$OMP& REDUCTION( + : dtemp )
      do 50 i = mp1,n,5
        dtemp = dtemp + dx(i)*dy(i) + dx(i + 1)*dy(i + 1) +
     *   dx(i + 2)*dy(i + 2) + dx(i + 3)*dy(i + 3) + dx(i + 4)*dy(i + 4)
   50 continue
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
   60 ddot = dtemp
      return
      end
```

I am new to the OpenMP commands and am pretty sure I have something funny in there that slows the whole thing down more than on a single core. Currently I have tried to run it on 4 threads on a slower 4(4) core machine where it actually went a bit faster than the large 20(40) core machine where we designated 12 threads for the processing. At this point I'm thinking the code is funny and doing something I don't want.

The Do loop higher up could be parallelized too, but I didn't know how to define the `ix` and `iy` and so just left it alone since it doesn't spend much time there.

Precision is very important, so the compiler is set to fp-mode precise. I don't know if that matters at all, but when the code does manage to generate answers they do appear correct. Basically, I'm just trying to figure out how to speed up this code, but instead parallel processing seems to slow down the process instead.

Comment: Uf, I suggest you to use `END DO` instead of `CONTINUE`, it is really hard to read the code.

Comment: Intel has done all the work of speeding up the linpack ddot for you in the MKL library.  Among other things, this involves discarding the unrolling by 5 and optimizing for the several target architectures.  You will likely see that single thread simd reduction is used up to a size of several thousand (and dot_product can take care of the smaller cases). fp-model precise prevents optimized reduction in order to avoid taking small improvements in accuracy out of users' control.

Comment: Intel usually says VIPO... "vector Inner" "parallel outer". I would change it all from "parallel do" to "do SIMD". If there is something to be gained then the parallel the outer most part. The VI part is easy, but any cache misses will make one go slower. If you have ifort, do you have vtune?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, both informative and helpful. Yeah, this is all based on some code my colleague used. I've been tasked with modernizing as much as I can. I'll try out changing to SIMD, and there is a larger outer loop I was planning on messing with next so I'll try parallel on that next.

Comment: It turns out I actually do have vtune, I have just never used it. I will have to look into its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of Intel Webinars you can look up help you.

I have aperture optimum histogram code that does OpenMP SIMD REDUCTION. So I decided to bring in the vector into a (big,nthreads) array and do each thread in a parallel region. Generally it runs slower than just using a single core. (I have not tried vtune on that yet)

Other similar array approaches with FFTs run faster, and the cores are all at 100% with good scaling.

Basically one either needs to work out the issues or test which works better. Any OpenMP parallel takes a long time to start, so you want it way outside, and not down at the tightest level.

Generally you can be better off with PURE functions or subroutines, and using

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VECTOR ...
```

In ifort16 there is also VECTOR(REF(variable)) and the reference is new.
Once all that is singing, then the parallel can be attempted.

Your DO 50 would need some big numbers for 'i' in order to make parallelised code go faster, or the OpenMP parallel 'startup' will gobble up too much time.

There is not a lot other than vtune to aid finding cashe misses (etc) to give you insight into getting to having faster code (which is really code without slowdowns). After all that, then it may be worthwhile to also compile using gfortran. I generally find that running through two compilers gives more insight into making better overall code. But if you get gains from !DEC$ Extensions, then gfortran may not help. CONTIGUOUS can also be worth trying in functions.